# Continuous linear operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis

My book says that $||Ax|| \leq M ||x|| \ \forall x \in X \implies ||A|| \leq M$, because $||A|| = sup_{||x|| \leq 1} \ ||Ax|| \in [0, M]$.

However, I'm unable to see how this follows from the definition. Thank you very much.

Comment: Because $\sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \|Ax\| \le M \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \|x\|$....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $x $ with $\|x\|=1$, $$
\|Ax\|\leq M. $$ So $M $ is an upper bound for the set $$\{\|Ax\|:\ \|x\|\leq1\}. $$ And thus
$$\sup\{\|Ax\|:\ \|x\|\leq1\}\leq M. $$